# Populate a C# array like a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class that contains some properties:

```
public class PossibleSettingsData
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Definition { get; set; }
    public object Meaning { get; set; }
}
```

and I have an array of this class and I want to instantiate it like a multi-dimensional array:

```
var PossibleSettings=new PossibleSettingsData[]
{
    { 5 ,"4800 baud", 4800}, \\It means I want to Value=5 and Definition="4800 baud" and Meaning=4800
    { 6 ,"9600 baud", 9600},
    { 7 ,"19200 baud" ,19200}
};
```

what changes do I have to make in `PossibleSettingsData` class to do this? Is it at all possible?
I have seen something like this when I want populate a `Dictionary<,>` so I think maybe I can do this.

Comment: Have you tried adding a constructor to `PossibleSettingsData` (int, string, object) which initializes the respective properties?

Comment: Yes, but I want to have a clean and abbreviated code. Because I don't want to type `new PossibleSettingsData` in every row.

Comment: This syntax works with dictionaries, because of the Add(TKey, TValue) method. The alternatives are already in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get that exact syntax, but if you want to do what `Dictionary` does, you need to define another type:

```
class PossibleSettingsDataList: IEnumerable<PossibleSettingsData> {
    private List<PossibleSettingsData> list = new();
    public void Add(int value, string definition, object meaning) {
        list.Add(new() {
            Value = value, Definition = definition, Meaning = meaning
        });
    }

    public IEnumerator<PossibleSettingsData> GetEnumerator()
        => ((IEnumerable<PossibleSettingsData>)list).GetEnumerator()

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => ((IEnumerable)list).GetEnumerator();
}
```

The important thing here is the `Add` method and the conformance to `IEnumerable<PossibleSettingsData>`. This allows the 3 things you put in your nested `{}`s be passed to the `Add` method. For more info, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers).

Then you can do:

```
var PossibleSettings=new PossibleSettingsDataList
{
    { 5 ,"4800 baud", 4800},
    { 6 ,"9600 baud", 9600},
    { 7 ,"19200 baud" ,19200}
}.ToArray();
```

Comment: I was looking for an IEnumerable to use in a foreach loop. I think it is exactly what I need. But I couldn't use some of your syntax like new(). I think it is related to the C# version I use.

Comment: @mohammad Yeah, it's called [target typed `new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new). You don't have to use it. You could just write the entire type name `List<PossibleSettingsData>`

Answer (score 2):

Adding a constructor:

```
public class PossibleSettingsData
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public string Definition { get; set; }
  public object Meaning { get; set; }
  public PossibleSettingsData()
  {
  }
  public PossibleSettingsData(int value, string definition, object meaning)
  {
    Value = value;
    Definition = definition;
    Meaning = meaning;
  }
}
```

We can write that:

```
var PossibleSettings = new PossibleSettingsData[]
{
  new PossibleSettingsData(5 ,"4800 baud", 4800), 
  new PossibleSettingsData(6 ,"9600 baud", 9600),
  new PossibleSettingsData(7 ,"19200 baud" ,19200)
};
```

But without the constructor:

```
var PossibleSettings = new PossibleSettingsData[]
{
  new PossibleSettingsData { Value = 5, Definition = "4800 baud", Meaning = 4800},
  new PossibleSettingsData { Value = 6, Definition = "9600 baud", Meaning = 9600},
  new PossibleSettingsData { Value = 7, Definition = "19200 baud", Meaning = 19200}
};
```

Also with C# 9+ we can write, if I understood (I use C# 7.3):

```
var PossibleSettings = new PossibleSettingsData[]
{
  new(5 ,"4800 baud", 4800),
  new(6 ,"9600 baud", 9600),
  new(7 ,"19200 baud" ,19200)
};
```

Of course we can create a specialized collection class as exposed by @Sweeper.

Comment: A C# 9 feature called "Positional records" can also be used, checkout the blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/#positional-records